# Proper way of freeing pointers when using method chaining

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I'm currently writing multiple different implementations of matrix multiplications in c. So I wrote utility functions for matrix addition and subtraction, which have the following structure:

```
int** m_sub(int** a, int** b, int size) {
    int **result = get_matrix(size);
    // calculate addition of a & b
    return result;
```

}

with `get_matrix():`

```
int** get_matrix(int size){
    int** m = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        m[i] = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    }
    return m;
```

}

I designed all functions to work with and return `int**` because to my understanding, you cannot return variable sized 2-D arrays in c.

Now the program works fine as is, however through running a memory checker (Valgrind) I discovered that all the return values from calls to, e.g. `m_add` are causing memory leaks, because I am using the returned value directly in method chaining and I don't `free()` them, e.g.:

```
m_copy(c_11,m_add(matmul_recursive(n/2, a,e),matmul_recursive(n/2, b, g), n/2), n/2);
```

I know I could fix this by assigning each returned `int**` to a variable and manually freeing it afterwards. However that would lead to a huge amount of temporarily assigned variables and thus (arguably) way less readable code.

Now I was wondering if there is a "proper" way of doing this in c? Or is the fact that I'm returning `int**` pointers for matrices already a bad design choice?

Comment: Can't you just do the reverse? free the `m[i]` pointers in a loop and finally free `**m`?

Comment: (@Inian means `free (m[i]);` in a loop and then `free (m);`)

Comment: Yes, I know how I can free the matrices I get from `get_matrix()` with a loop. The question is more "can i free them even though I don't assign the returned `int**` to a variable but use it directly as a parameter for another function?"

Comment: `int** m = malloc(size*sizeof(int));` is very wrong, it assumes the size of a pointer is the size of an integer. It should be `int **m = malloc(size * sizeof *m);`, i.e. `sizeof (int *)` but without repeating the type and with a little bit of "locking" to the variable in question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C has no notion of automatic destructor call, as C++ as. So AFAIK, you as the programmer are responsable to free anything that has been allocated.

Of course, you can imagine a library that keeps references of anything it has allocated and provide a way to free that when you no longer need it. For example, you could implement a dynamic stack to store each newly allocated memory block, and use that stack to reclaim the whole memory later.

Simply I am too lazy to write an implementation of it... But feel free to ping me in a comment if you feel you want to do that but cannot implement it from the beginning.

Comment: I've been thinking of something similar. So you would suggest having some kind of 'global' stack within the computations and push all temporary variables onto that, right?

Comment: Exactly. It could be a static member in the compilation unit containing the routines for allocation and deallocation - beware, do not forget to explicitely initialize it because again C has no automatic constructor call. Alternatively, it could be a parameter given to the allocation/deallocation routines.

Comment: You can use `at_exit` as a "poor man's destructor", but it is poor indeed since it can only be used to free objects at program termination, not when they are no longer used.

Comment: +1 for the stack idea. being responsible for the memory does not necessary mean you cannot write abstractions helping you.

Comment: @Lundin I think at that point the only real benefit would be making `valgrind` happy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually manually freeing each pointer is the proper way to do it in C since as Serge wrote there is no automatic destructor call in C. However you can make it manual and pretty without resorting to a dynamic stack or a garbage collector like solutions which in my opinion would usually be a huge overkill. So without further ado.

1. Name the creator function so that it is clear it allocates memory like create... or allocate... or new... and not get. Let's assume create/delete nomenclature here. So:

   `int* create_matrix(int size);`

Note I am using `int*`, not `int**`. It is more convenient, does not require you to do all the second dimension allocations, you simply allocate one array of size `n*n`. In memory this is the same space. You may however stick to 2 dimensions if you prefer.

2. Next the destructor

   `void delete_matrix(int* matrix);`
3. Now that we have some pretty syntax, we modify your operation prototypes. Instead of taking two arrays and returning a newly allocated one, operate on the first argument. Your multiplication function allocating data is not good as it is not intuitive to assume that multiplication allocates new data instead of returning it by value. So:

   `int* matmul_recursive(int* left, const int* right, int size);`

Note we will not be modifying `right`, hence the const. We will be modifying `left` hence no const. Now write your multiplication of `left` and `right` and put your results into `left`. No additional allocation means no leaks. The function should return `left` for convenience chained calls.

Note that you can add a `int* create_matrix_copy(const int* source, int size);` to clone a matrix.

Note also that you will typically not be needing the arguments of the operations after the operations. You will be interested in the resulting cumulated matrix. See this sample (using your function names):

```
int* arg1 = create_matrix(n);
int* arg2 = create_matrix(n);
int* product1 = create_matrix(n);
int* product2 = create_matrix(n);
int* result = m_add(matmul_recursive(product1, arg1, n), matmul_recursive(product2, arg2, n), n);
delete_matrix(arg1);
delete_matrix(arg2);
delete_matrix(product2);
printf("%d", product1[0]);
printf("%d", result[0]); // result == product1
delete_matrix(product1);
```

Also use `const` whenever applicable i.e. you do not change the value of the argument, heplps avoid mistakes. Also consider using `unsigned int` for sizes.

Also more often then not you will probably do many operations on one matrix, hence this will be more common (like 3D transformations):

```
int* result = create_matrix(n);
int* rotate = create_matrix(n);
int* translate = create_matrix(n);
int* scale = create_matrix(n);
matmul_recursive(matmul_recursive(matmul_recursive(result, rotate, n), translate, n), scale, n);
printf("%d", result[0]);
// Remember to delete all arguments.
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer, I think I got it. One question though: I cannot use in-place modifications as you proposed in my case since for the algorithm I'm implementing I may need `int **c1 = m_add(a, b)` and after that, e.g. `int** c2 = m_sub(c, a)`. So I can't modify `a` at the first statement. How would you go about that ?

Answer (score 0):

In `C` you do not have the luxuries you have in `C++`, so memory de-allocation is left to you only.  If you really want to avoid de-allocation the matrices one by one you can do something like the following:

To create a `struct` that is responsible for the storage of all the addresses of the created matrices (let's call it container).

1. So your functions will take also a pointer to this matrix container object. When get_matrix is called the address of the newly allocated matrix is added to the container.
2. All you need to do at the end of the calculation, is to properly free the container.

Something like the following (pseudocode below):

```
int** get_matrix(int size, struct MatricesContainer* cnt){ //takes the container
    int** m = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
        m[i] = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    }
    vector_push_back(m, cnt); //push_the address in the container
    return m;
}

int** m_sub(int** a, int** b, int size, struct MatricesContainer* cnt) {
    int **result = get_matrix(size, cnt); //address of result is stored in cnt
    // calculate addition of a & b
    return result;
}
```

and use it normally and then destroying it in a function

```
int heavy_calculation(...)
{
struct MatricesContainer* cnt
   .....
   m_copy(c_11,m_add(matmul_recursive(n/2, a,e, cnt),matmul_recursive(n/2, b, g,cnt),   n/2), n/2,cnt); 
   ...
   destroy_container(cnt);
}
```

`destroy_container` loops over the vector of matrices and frees them one by one.

Please not that as stated in the comment `get_matrix` has problems. `int** m = malloc(size*sizeof(int));` should be `int** m = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));` as you need to allocate space for pointers and not for `int`s.